# How to initialize a Ref<?> field in objectify to a dummy value

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have a collection(arraylist) of Ref `s ,the objectify documentation says that I need to initialize collections for them to be persisted and hence modified in the future.....

Now , Ref points to an object but when I launch my app for the first time I dont have any objects in the data store...so whats the best way for me to initialize a dummy value...... 
Is my assumption that a Ref<> needs to point to a real object in the data store?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You should just initialize an empty collection.  You don't need to add anything to it. eg, `field = new ArrayList<Ref<Thing>>();`
2. It's actually not even required that you initialize the collection.  It's just a good idea for reasons that will become apparent if you use the system for a while.

Comment: Thanks a bunch "stickfigure".....what I ended up doing was creating a dummy object and adding it to the arraylist..... but what you are telling me is that initializing an empty collection will persist it to the data store?  The documentation says that "Null or empty collections are not written to the datastore and therefore get ignored during load"......and that kinda confused me into adding a dummy value....

Comment: That's correct. There is no internal datastore representation of an empty list, which is fine, because absence of data simply means your POJO field is left as-is. If you want to distinguish between a null collection and an empty collection... don't - use an additional (say, boolean) variable.